# Cannot reference a view created via xml

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

I follow [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play) (with XML part) to add AdMob view.

When I compile compiler says `package R does not exist` on this line:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

And in gen folder I cannot find and `R` file generated for `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`. How to ask Eclipse to generate it?

Comment: Can you post your xml?

Comment: @AlexBalo please follow the link and click on "Create your banner in XML". You will see there the xml I have copied.

Comment: But did you add the AdSdk?

Comment: Usually if `R` is missing that means there was an error in your XML, or some other problem in the `res` directory such as a file with a badly formed name.

Comment: @ajb I have there two files: layouts.xml and main.xml. In none of these xml there is an error. But when I deleted one of them, and imported corresponding package name (import com.company.application.R;) it worked.

Comment: An error in the XML could cause the R file missing, becuase it cannot build the project. To try rebuild it click `Project -> Clean`

Comment: @Narek Eclipse doesn't always catch all errors in the XML.  I've run into cases where there aren't any red markers indicating an error but there are still errors preventing the Android tools from processing the XML.  The last time this happened to me, I had an extra space character that the tool treated as a syntax error.